# Can't adjust data feed position on web page regardless of css

Tags: html, css, feed

I'm trying to implement the data feed that Box Office Mojo offers from their website, and they say that adding this line of code should display the feed:

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php">`

Which works, but I have the issue of it positioned on the far left side of the page by default, which looks weird (warning, large image).

[image: Box Office Mojo feed]

I wrapped said script in a `p` tag, like so:

`<p id="boxOffice"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php"></script></p>`

and styling tag with `position`, but none of the options that I have tried have moved it. Have any of you guys had any idea of moving it? I'm stuck here.

Comment: The script must add an element to your page which is what renders the feed, you'll need to inspect it and see what it is (probably an `<iframe>.`) and you'll need to position *that* element. A `<script>` tag is not displayable and wrapping it inside a `<p>` won't actually do anything.

Comment: I checked the page that offered the line of code and it's only wrapped in a `table`. I tried that and used `align` like they did, but it still doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want it in the center? There are multiple ways to do that.

**Method 1.** Using `<center>` tag

```
<center><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php"></script></center>
```

Your table should be centered like this:
[image]

**Method 2.** Add below code after the `<head>` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
</style>
```

It will do the same.

**Method 3.** Using `<div>` tag:

```
<div class="mytable"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php"></script></div>
```

And you can play with css to put the table anywhere you want:

```
.mytable {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is my full code for method 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php"></script></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haha, this worked! There's a time frame for the bounty award, so I'll do i tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: @Asking I updated the answer, actually you can try any of these methods.

Comment: Hmm, I tried all three and only your original answer, method 2, seemed to work.

Comment: That's strange, because they all works for me. Here is my full code: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php"></script></center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ups, comments doesn't support code, i will edit and add full code to the end of my answer

Comment: Still not getting methods 1 and 3 to work. Could be related to the link that they provided that this is happening. It's fine, however, I managed to get at least something to work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i would suggest that try using `<DIV>`tag instead of `<p>`tag.
it should Work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #boxOffice{
                float:right;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="boxOffice"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php"></script></div>
</body></html>
```

You can also use other css properties with `<DIV>`.

or

You can use `<center>`tag with `<p>` tag to align it to center.

`<center><p id="boxOffice"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/wknd5.php"></script></p></center>`